Number of ways to arrange $n$ people in circles
First I want to point out that this is NOT the problem of arranging $n$ in ONE circle, for those who are rushing to close my question.
Now for the problem: in how many ways can $n$ people be arranged in circles, such that there is no order between the circles, but there is order inside every circle?
Well, it can be shown, using recursion, that the solution must satisfy $T(n)=n\cdot T(n-1)$, with $T(0)=1$. Thus we can quickly deduce that the solution is $n!$.
However, the question is different. I have to find a non-recursive method to solve this. What I thought of is defining some bijection between the set of solutions to the known problem of arranging $n$ people in a row, which the size of is $n!$. For example, I can define "separators" between the people after arranging them. Like, arranging the people - $n!$ and then putting separators to define the circles - $2^{n-1}$. However this way, this method produces order between the circles, and i'm not sure how to get rid of it.
Any help or other ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Hint:  Consider the cycle structure of a permutation on $n$ letters. Each permutation is uniquely determined by its cycle structure.

Can you elaborate? I'm not sure what you mean by a cycle structure.

Every permutation breaks the $n$ objects into cycles.  For instance, in $S_5$, we might have $(132)(45)$.  That permutation maps $1\mapsto 3\mapsto 2\mapsto 1$ and $4\mapsto 5\mapsto 4$.  Given that, we put $(1,3,2)$ in one circle, and $(4,5)$ in antother.

See this article for instance.

Hmm, why exactly? What prevents me from choosing $(13)(2)(45)$ for example?

No problem, that's a different permutation.  That one takes $1\mapsto 3\mapsto 1$, $4\mapsto 5\mapsto 4$ and $2$ is a fixed point.  So, put $(1,3)$ in one circle, $2$ in another, and $(4,5)$ in a third.  there are $n!$ permutations and each one has a distinct cycle pattern.

But I got this different cycle from the same exact permutation $13245$, didn't I?

Nope.  In my first example, $3\mapsto 2\mapsto 1$.  In your example, $3\mapsto 1$ and $2\mapsto 2$.  Different permutation.  Obviously, if I know what a permutation does to each of the $n$ objects, I know the permutation.

To be clear, the $5$ cycle $(13245)$ is yet another permuation.  That one is $1\mapsto 3\mapsto 2\mapsto 4\mapsto 5\mapsto 1$.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I suggest:  look at the article I linked to.  There are lots of ways to write out permutations, the method I am describing is pretty standard but it is not the only one people use.

I see, I think the only thing I was missing is why can I do it. And the person who wrote the answer below is what I was looking for.

There are clearly $n!$ bijections from $\{1,\dots,n\}$ to itself as each bijection $f:\{1,\dots,n\}\rightarrow\{1,\dots,n\}$ uniquely corresponds to a sequence $f(1),f(2),\dots,f(n)$ of distinct integers from $1$ to $n$.
We can label each person with a distinct integer from the set $\{1,\dots,n\}$.
Define a bijective function $f:\{1,\dots,n\}\rightarrow\{1,\dots,n\}$ such that $f(x)=$ the person clockwise from the person labelled $x$. Each bijective function $f$ uniquely determines a way of arranging people.
For example, $f(1)=2,f(2)=3,f(3)=4,f(4)=5,f(5)=1,f(6)=6$ corresponds with this way of arranging people:

There are $n!$ bijections so there are $n!$ different arrangements of people.

+1 : Elegant...

Wow... this works. Very elegant indeed, thanks a lot.

We want to find the number of sets of cycles of $n$ people.  A solution by way of exponential generating functions follows.
The EGF of the number of cycles of $n$ people is
$$\ln \left( \frac{1}{1-x} \right)$$
so the EGF of the number of sets of such cycles is
$$\exp \left( \ln \left( \frac{1}{1-x} \right) \right) = \frac{1}{1-x}$$
and we recognize $1/(1-x)$ as the EGF of $n!$, so the number of sets of cycles is $n!$.
